# Given a para of words (separated by space), create a 2D array where each array in it represents the word. Note that the words are of the same size

Tags: java, arrays

Sample Input #1

to2DChars("bat sat put mat")

Sample Output #1

{{'b','a','t'},{'s','a','t'},{'p','u','t'},{'m','a','t'}}

```
enter code here
public char[][] to2DChars(String words){
     
      
       int row=0;
        int index=words.indexOf(' ');
        int col=index;
        while(index!=-1){
        row++;
        index=words.indexOf(' ',index+1);
        }
        row++;
        char[][] c=new char[row][col];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        c[i][j]=words.charAt(i+k);
        k++;
        }
        }
        return c;
      
   }
```

trying above code but it fails on 3rd test case? as how it gives null.?

Testcase    Pass/Fail   Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output

## 1  Pass    'hi is to'  {{'h','i'};{'i','s'};{'t','o'}}     {{'h','i'};{'i','s'};{'t','o'}}

## 2  Pass    'a b c d'   {{'a'};{'b'};{'c'};{'d'}}   {{'a'};{'b'};{'c'};{'d'}}

## 3  Fail    'hello'     null    {{'h','e','l','l','o'}}

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` and `toCharArray()`.

```
String s = "hi is to";
String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
char[][] arr = new char[tokens.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = tokens[i].toCharArray();
}
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; ++j)
    {
       System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
     }
}
```